# Steps to prove or disprove if two rings are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, proof-writing, group-isomorphism

So i'm struggling on how to prove if two rings are not isomorphic to one another. My professor told me that if a ring is not isomorphic to another, the best way to prove that this is true is to find a preserved property of isomorphisms that is not held.
So i considered the following:
1.Q and R (quotients and rationals)

2.$~~\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$ (Z mod 4 cross Z mod 4 and Z mod 16)

I cannot seem to think of any of the properties:
communicative, identity, integral domain, and field property that do not hold for rings. My professor told me this it isnt enough to give an example mapping like F: Q -> R and show that it isnt isomorphic.
Hence, how can i show that these two problems above arent isomorphic?

Can anyone give me some finite steps to prove is something is isomorphic to something or not?

Comment: By $Q$ and $R$, do you mean the rationals $\mathbb Q$ and the reals $\mathbb R$?

Comment: yep, sorry about that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: $Z_{16}$ has an element of additive order $16$. Does $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$?

**Added:** You don’t want to confine your attention to ‘big’ properties like commutativity or being an integral domain; often the differences are only to be found at a more detailed level.

Comment: oh okay, i see that if I have a map like: f: Z16 -> Z4 X Z4 then i say f(1)= (1,1) i can find f(4)=f(0) but 4 != 0 and that proves that f isnt isomorphic, but i dont think that is enough to say that Z16 and Z4 x Z4 is not isomorphic because that is just one example of a function that doesnt work

Comment: @mazie: You are correct in thinking that it’s not enough to show that this one function doesn’t work. Try to show instead that if $f$ is an isomorphism, and the additive order of $x$ is $n$, then the additive order of $f(x)$ must also be $n$. Group isomorphisms preserve order, so ring isomorphisms preserve additive order. Then if you show that $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$ has no element of additive order $16$, you’ll have shown that there can be no isomorphism from $Z_{16}$ to it.

Comment: so could i instead say that since [1]16 had an addivitve order of 16 but f(1)= (1,1) and (1,1) has an addivitve order of 4, thus the sets are not isomorphic. I'm just confused because my book has an example with Z4 and Z2xZ2 and says that f: Z4-> Z2xZ2 and that f(2)= f(1+1)= f(1)+f(1)= (1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0) but f(0)=(0,0) -> not one to one

Comment: @mazie: You’re still trying to look at a specific $f$, one that sends $1$ to $\langle 1,1\rangle$. **Don’t.** Prove the general result that every ring isomorphism preserves additive order, so that if $f:\Bbb Z_{16}\to\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$ were an isomorphism, $f(1)$ would have to have additive order $16$. Then prove that no element of $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$ has additive order $16$. This will demonstrate that there is no isomorphism between the two groups. \\ The example is doing something different: it’s showing that **if** $f:\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is defined by setting ...

Comment: ... $f(1)=\langle 1,1\rangle$, **then** that $f$ is not an isomorphism. This does not prove that the two groups are not isomorphic; it just shows that this particular $f$ isn’t an isomorphism between them. In fact they are not isomorphic, and one way to prove this uses the idea that I’ve been suggesting: $1$ has additive order $4$ in $\Bbb Z_4$, but no element of $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ has additive order $4$.

Comment: oh okay i see now, with your example your considering just each ring itself instead of a mapping like it did.  So how about for two non isomorphic sets that are infinite in size, like Q and R? Since you used an additive order property that is preserved, do you know any good books or sites that list properties preserved in isomorphisms?

Comment: @mazie: With $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ it’s easy: they aren’t the same cardinality, so there isn’t even a bijection between them, let alone a ring isomorphism. \\ I’d be a bit surprised to find an actual list of such properties, because once you really understand the notion of isomorphism, it’s pretty easy to identify them. Isomorphic rings can be thought of as the *same* ring, but with a different set of names attached to the elements. An isomorphism is then a kind of dictionary that allows you to translate the name of an element in one version to the name of the ‘same’ element in the other ...

Comment: ... version. Clearly the order of an element is something that can’t change just because we use a different name for the element: it’s a structural property of the element itself.

Comment: Oh i see, that makes much more sense now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @mazie: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

1.

The rationals $\mathbb Q$ and the reals $\mathbb R$ are not isomorphic because they don't have the same cardinality.

If you want an algebraic reason, there is an element $u \in \mathbb R$ such that $u^2=2$ but there is not such element in $\mathbb Q$.

In fact, every ring homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ must be the inclusion, and so cannot be surjective.

2.

Consider the idempotents in each ring, that is the solutions of $x^2=x$.

The idempotents of $\mathbb Z_{16}$ are $0$ and $1$ but there are at least $4$ idempotents in $\mathbb Z_{4}\times \mathbb Z_{4}$, namely $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

As to your final question, no: there is no general routine that would always work in finitely many steps to decide whether two rings are isomorphic.  At your stage you will probably benefit more from Brian M. Scott's tips on how to approach the specific problem you raised.  But your closing question is meaningful, and its answer is no.